Install eclipses paho.mqtt.cpp repo as static library
Hi I try for a while now to get the mqtt.paho.cpp from eclispe on my machine (windows 11) to use it as a static library for project in QNX (embeded).
I follow the step as told in the readme of the repository, but when i get to the point to call the follwoing command on cmd:
cmake -Bbuild -H. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mqtt\paho-cpp -DPAHO_BUILD_SAMPLES=ON -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=OFF -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mqtt\paho-c
I always get the following error

-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22631.
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:84 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "paho-mqttpp3-static" links to:

    eclipse-paho-mqtt-c::paho-mqtt3a-static

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.



-- Generating done (0.1s)
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

I have absolutely no clue about cmake, so i would appreciate some help.
Thx!
I tried by downloading the zip and unpacking it and also just cloning it.
I also added the find_package in the cmake, but the i jsut got a extra error like this
CMake Warning at src/CMakeLists.txt:29 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindC:\mqtt\paho-c.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "C:\mqtt\paho-c", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "C:\mqtt\paho-c"
  with any of the following names:

    C:\mqtt\paho-cConfig.cmake
    c:\mqtt\paho-c-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "C:\mqtt\paho-c" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "C:\mqtt\paho-c_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "C:\mqtt\paho-c" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


CMake Warning at src/CMakeLists.txt:84 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindC:\mqtt\paho-c.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "C:\mqtt\paho-c", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "C:\mqtt\paho-c"
  with any of the following names:

    C:\mqtt\paho-cConfig.cmake
    c:\mqtt\paho-c-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "C:\mqtt\paho-c" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "C:\mqtt\paho-c_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "C:\mqtt\paho-c" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.

